# Big-O notation representation of a simple algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

How can I represent its complexity with Big-O notation? I am little bit confused since the second for loop changes according to the index of the outer loop. Is it still O(n^2)? or less complex? Thanks in advance

```
for (int k = 0; k<arr.length; k++){
      for (m = k; m<arr.length; m++){
           //do something
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your estimation comes from [progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) formula:

[image]

and, thus, is `O(n^2)`. Why your case is progression? Because it's `n + (n-1) + ... + 1` summation for your loops.

Answer (score 3):

If you add all iterations of the second loop, you get 1+2+3+...+n, which is equal with n(n+1)/2 (n is the array length). That is n^2/2 + n/2. As you may already know, the relevant term in big-oh notation is the one qith the biggest power, and coeficients are not relevant. So, your complexity is still O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

well the runtime is cca half of the n^2 loop

- but in big O notation it is still O(n^2)
- because any constant time/cycle - operation is represented as O(1)
- so  O((n^2)/2) -> O((n^2)/c) -> O(n^2)
- unofficially there are many people using O((n^2)/2) including me for own purposes (its more intuitive and comparable) ... closer to cycle/runtime

hope it helps